# MATLAB: Adding a legend to the bottom of a figure without changing figure width or resizing plots

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

I am constantly running into issues with the legend in MATLAB plots and would like to come up with a way to avoid them in the future.

What I would like to do is the following:

1. Create a figure with a fixed size:

   `f = figure('Position',[0 0 800 600]`)
2. Plot whatever it is that I would like to plot in this figure

   `x = -pi:0.01:pi

   plot(x,sin(x),x,cos(x),x,tan(x))`
3. Adding a legend to the plot at the **bottom** of the figure, without resizing the plot (I am fine with making the figure "taller" so to speak", but I would like the legend to go beneat the plot, the axis and everything else). If possible, I would also like to use the [legendflex](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/31092) package to create the legend (not sure if this will induce any issues).

Does anyone know how I could go about this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am using Octave, rather than MATLAB, but does the following work (or at least get you closer to what you want)?

```
% Create the figure and plot
f = figure('Position',[0 0 800 600]);
x = -pi:0.01:pi;
plot(x,sin(x),x,cos(x),x,tan(x));

% Set axes and figure units to pixels, get current positions
set(f,'Units','pixels')
set(gca,'Units','pixels')
fig_pos = get(f,'position');
old_ax_pos = get(gca,'position');

% Add a legend et get its position too
h = legend('L1','L2','L3','location','southoutside');
set(h,'Units','pixels')
leg_pos = get(h,'position');

% Get the new axes position, look at how much it shifted
new_ax_pos = get(gca,'position');
pixel_shift = new_ax_pos - old_ax_pos; % y position shift is positive (axes moved up), y height shift is negative (axes got smaller)

% Make figure taller and restore axes height to their initial value
set(f,'position',fig_pos - [0 0 0 pixel_shift(4)]);
set(h,'position',leg_pos)
set(gca,'position',old_ax_pos + [0 pixel_shift(2) 0 0])

% Create a new figure without legend for comparing
f2 = figure('Position',[0 0 800 600]);
x = -pi:0.01:pi;
plot(x,sin(x),x,cos(x),x,tan(x));
```

Arnaud